# How can i do unfocusable a element of my user interface?

Tags: android, focus

i have a element, that i want to be disabled in a situation.

ok. i do it with this:

Weekend.setEnabled(false);

ok, but it still remains focusable, i mean that when user press down/up keys or moves the scroll, the element still can get the focus (orange colour).

i tryed with this:

Weekend.setEnabled(false);
Weekend.setFocusable(false);
Weekend.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

but doesn't works!!!! it still can be oranged when user press up/down keys and moves the windows with the scrollbar

Comment: Are you using gridview by any chance?

Comment: no im using linearlayout, relativelayout etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a non-focusable property you can set, but you could use an onFocusChangeListener to move the focus to a different element when your disabled one becomes focused.